# Searching in serial for certain words WHILE reading?

Tags: arduino

When reading serial sometimes the input data is too large to save, but we need to search inside it anyway , for a certain words .

Right now we accumulate all the data and only then look for the specific word.
I would like to do that `while reading, without saving the data` , so to improve this one :

```
   boolean waitFor(char  *target, long timeout)
        {

                unsigned long tm=millis();
                  while( 1 )
                  {
                    if( millis() - tm >= timeout ) 
                      return 0;

                    char wifiContent[50]={0};
                    int readWifiIndex=0;

                    while( wifiSerial.available()  ) 
                    {  

                        if(readWifiIndex<50)
                        {                 
                             wifiContent[readWifiIndex]=(char)wifiSerial.read();
                             readWifiIndex++;
                             delay(1);  
                        } 


                    }


                //**check of specific words 
                    if( strstr(wifiContent,target) )
                       return 1;


                  }

        }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For anyone who needs it, here is a more elegant solution, which is much less heavy , and saves lots of resources .

This function search for a given word, and has a timeout also . works great .

```
boolean waitFor(char  *target, long timeout)
    {

            unsigned long tm=millis();
              while( 1 )
              {
                if( millis() - tm >= timeout ) 
                  return 0;


                int readWifiIndex=0;

                while( Serial.available()  ) 
                {  


                         char cr=(char)Serial.read();
                         delay(1);  

                         if(target[readWifiIndex] ==cr)
                         {
                          readWifiIndex++;
                          if(  strlen(target) ==readWifiIndex )
                          return 1;
                         }
                         else
                         readWifiIndex=0;




                }
```